# Rails 5.2 Auth - Token returned after create_new_auth_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, devise-token-auth

I am using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) and I met a weird scenario.

I have only one user in my database, and when I ask in the console for his tokens, I get this:

```
$ user.tokens

{
    "_5_Mh40SfQvsnkerykJMIw"=>{
        "token"=>"$2a$10$EScwGJLVba9oN1uek0m0bOy6.nyRq9q6yFO25nKbiPCOslUEwBrFi",
        "expiry"=>1527942239,
        "last_token"=>nil,
        "updated_at"=>"2018-05-19T14:23:59.127+02:00"
    }
}
```

so now I want a new token, so I execute the following:

```
$ user.create_new_auth_token
```

And this is the response to that call

```
"access-token"=>"Uof0cB0KcI5RH-GFOCezDw",
"token-type"=>"Bearer",
"client"=>"J_Bb35u9pcBCUSLuzP8axA",
"expiry"=>"1527942277",
"uid"=>"eddie@me.com"
```

Which should be the new token, right? So I check again the tokens of the user:

```
$ user.tokens

{
    "_5_Mh40SfQvsnkerykJMIw"=>{
        "token"=>"$2a$10$EScwGJLVba9oN1uek0m0bOy6.nyRq9q6yFO25nKbiPCOslUEwBrFi",
        "expiry"=>1527942239,
        "last_token"=>nil,
        "updated_at"=>"2018-05-19T14:23:59.127+02:00"
    },
    "J_Bb35u9pcBCUSLuzP8axA"=>{
        "token"=>"$2a$10$trmOQQOnQRfMXGk0s8XS5ufUl9OHDnPcK7f4M4qXfGggj4gCUIc12",
        "expiry"=>1527942277,
        "last_token"=>nil,
        "updated_at"=>"2018-05-19T14:24:37.637+02:00"
    }
}
```

Now, do you see the problem? The new client `J_Bb35u9pcBCUSLuzP8axA`matches but the `access-token` I received when I created the new token (`Uof0cB0KcI5RH-GFOCezDw`) does not match with the one stored in the database (`$2a$10$trmOQQOnQRfMXGk0s8XS5ufUl9OHDnPcK7f4M4qXfGggj4gCUIc12`)

Why is that? I thought that the response, when creating a new token, would
be that same token. What does the `access-token` mean? What is it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is that? I thought that the response, when creating a new token, would be that same token.

That happens because the `access-token` is saved encrypted in the DB, as explained [here](https://maicolben.gitbooks.io/devise-token-auth/content/docs/security.html).

> What does the access-token mean? What is it for?

It is a token that serves as the client's access identification (like a password) for every request, so it should not be stored as plain text.